# Web scraping through maps nested in a map

Tags: web-scraping

I have [a web page with a map containing districts](https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/1/event/2/shape/53148/shape_type/1?data_type=official). I can click on the different districts of this map and it takes me to the precincts of the district. From this map of the precincts of a given district I can download the csv.

[image: ![enter image description here]

I would like to get them all. How do I browse all the districts of the map with a script ?

I tried to look at what made the map to get the coordinates of the polygons that represents the district but it seems to be from a script when looking at [the source page](http://view-source:https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/1/event/2/shape/53148) :

```
...
    <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
window.gon={};gon.is_mobile=false;gon.is_bot=false;gon.is_ie=false;gon.no_data_text="No Data";gon.no_data_color="#CCCCCC";gon.tile_url="https://tile.openstreetmap.org/${z}/${x}/${y}.png";gon.openlayers_img_path="/assets/img/";gon.datatable_i18n_url="";gon.is_voters_list=false;gon.shape_path="/en/json/shape/53148/shape_type/1";gon.children_shapes_path="/en/json/custom_children_shapes/53148/shape_type/3";gon.data_path="/en/json/summary_custom_children_data/53148/shape_type/3/event/2/indicator_type/2?custom_view=true&data_set_id=2&data_type=official";gon.indicator_menu_data_path_summary="/en/json/summary_custom_children_data/53148/shape_type/3/event/2/indicator_type/xxx?custom_view=true&data_set_id=2&data_type=official";gon.indicator_menu_data_path="/en/json/custom_children_data/53148/shape_type/3/event/2/indicator/xxx?custom_view=true&data_set_id=2&data_type=official";gon.summary_view_type_name="summary";gon.indicator_description="District Winners";gon.event_id="2";gon.event_name="2008 Presidential";gon.map_title="Country: Georgia - Districts";gon.parent_shape_id="53148";gon.data_type="official";gon.data_type_live="live";gon.data_set_id="2";gon.data_set_id_most_recent=2;gon.history_url="https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/event_type/1/event/2/shape_type/1/shape/53148/indicator_type/2/view_type/summary/custom_view/true";gon.history_id=2;gon.data_table_path="/en/data_table/event_type/1/event/2/shape/53148/shape_type/1/child_shape_type/3/indicator/null/view_type/summary/summary_view_type/summary/custom_view/true?data_set_id=2&data_type=official&ind_order_explanation=Country%3A+Georgia&indicator_type_id=2";gon.dt_highlight_shape=false;gon.indicator_menu_scale=true;gon.openlayers=true;
//]]>
</script>
...
```

So I can't get map bbox coordinates when entering and the size in Window pixels to make a transformation from map coordinates to pixels on screen in order to click on the correct places on the screen.

Comment: Please share your code. Also, what language, framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your user history, I'm going to supply the answer in python (just a guess). If you go to one of the districts and download the csv, you will see a post request to https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/download-data.csv with a lot of form data. The 3 important (dynamic) ones are authenticity_token, shape_id, and map_title. After looking through the main url for any time of information reguarding this. I came across the url: https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/json/summary_custom_children_data/53148/shape_type/3/event/2/indicator_type/2?custom_view=true&data_set_id=2&data_type=official  which has json data with the shape id and district names of all the districts. The authenticity token can be found on the main url. While looping through each district, post request to the download csv url and save the data to a csv file.

(`pip install requests`)

```py
import requests

shape_id_json = requests.get(
    'https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/json/summary_custom_children_data/53148/shape_type/3/event/2/indicator_type/2?custom_view=true&data_set_id=2&data_type=official').json()
district_unique = {district[0]['shape_values']['shape_name']: district[0]['shape_values']['shape_id'] for district in
                   shape_id_json['shape_data'] if district[0]['shape_values']['shape_name']}
#
download_link = 'https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/download-data.csv'

subdistrict_districts = {}
for district_name, shape_id in district_unique.items():
    r = requests.post(download_link,
                      data={'map_title': f'District: {district_name} - Precincts', 'event_name': '2008 Presidential',
                            'event_id': 2, 'child_shape_type_id': 4, 'shape_type_id': 3, 'shape_id': shape_id,
                            'data_set_id': 2})
    if 'html' in r.content.decode():
        print(f'District {district_name} has subdistricts')
        subdistrict_districts[district_name] = shape_id
    else:
        with open(f'csv\\{district_name}.csv', 'wb') as f:
            print(district_name, shape_id)
            f.write(r.content)

for district_s, s_shape_id in subdistrict_districts.items():
    district_page = 'https://data.electionsportal.ge/en/json/summary_children_data/{}/shape_type/7/event/2/indicator_type/2/parent_clickable/false?data_set_id=2&data_type=official'.format(
        s_shape_id)
    district_page_json = requests.get(district_page).json()

    subdistrict_unique = {district[0]['shape_values']['shape_name']: district[0]['shape_values']['shape_id'] for
                          district in district_page_json['shape_data'] if district[0]['shape_values']['shape_name']}
    for subdistrict_name, subdistrict_shape_id in subdistrict_unique.items():
        r = requests.post(download_link,
                          data={'map_title': f'{district_s} District: {subdistrict_name} - {district_s} Precincts',
                                'event_name': '2008 Presidential',
                                'event_id': 2, 'child_shape_type_id': 8, 'shape_type_id': 7,
                                'shape_id': subdistrict_shape_id,
                                'data_set_id': 2})
        with open(f'csv\\{district_s} - {subdistrict_name}.csv', 'wb') as f:
            print(district_s, subdistrict_name, subdistrict_shape_id)
            f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really didn't know how to go through all these districts. However I had the `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'csv\\Kobuleti.csv'` error that I get rid of using `open(f'{district_name}.csv', 'wb') as f`. But when I open it I find that it is only the soure code of the webpage rather than the dowloadable csv file.

Comment: I mean when I open some districts. Probably the bigger ones like Tbilisi where you can dive one level deeper

Comment: Try to remove the line that starts with `s.headers`

Comment: When I was trying to write the code and I made an incomplete request, it also gave me the html of the webpage rather than the csv. However, the above works for me which is strange. I tried changing something in the code again, but if it doesn't work then I can't help you because it works for me.

Comment: Even for Tbilisi ?Tbilisi is very specific as it has subdistricts (there is a map inside the map before getting to the precincts level). Anyway, your code is great, there is just this problem with this messy case.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean, I thought you were saying that none of them were working. Do you want to just download the csv when Tbilisi is clicked or do you want the csv of each subdistrict in Tbilisi.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'm not native, I don't manage all the English subtleness yet. I would be very glad if you were able to get each the csv of each subdistrict in Tbilisi. I tried to craft it myself with recurrent function but ... nah

Comment: Okay, the code is fully updated. I also found a mistake in the first one in which the proper csv files weren't getting the proper name and now everything is fixed. It will check to see if an error has occured (because the first piece of code can't get the csv of subdistricts) and then it will later download all of the csv of the substricts.

Comment: Many thanks ! I m sure it will help to finish my essay on how democracy is running there. I think I've been able to transform it with functions to get it for all elections. I now have a knew idea to transform the csvs of every elections for every districts to a csv of one district with all elections. Do you mind having a look at it [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58238854/merge-and-create-columns-of-csv-files-based-on-their-names) whenever you have the time ?

Comment: Sorry to dig up this already old question but would you know how to keep the shape file in order to use it again?