# group and combine files with common prefixes

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I made a few functions that help me download all csv of elections by precincts. The names of the downloaded files look like this :

```
Hzwpukgh_2008Parliamentary-Majoritarian
Hzwpukgh_2008Parliamentary-PartyList
Hzwpukgh_2008Presidential
...
Truc_2008Presidential
```

It gives me, for a given election and a given precinct, the following :

```
"Election"," Map Level"," Precinct ID"," Precinct Name","Overall Results","#1 - Mikheil Saakashvili","#2 - Levan Gachechiladze","#3 - Shalva Natelashvili","#4 - Arkadi (Badri) Patarkatsishvili","#5 - Davit Gamkrelidze","#6 - Giorgi (Gia) Maisashvili","#7 - Irina Sarishvili-Chanturia","Total Voter Turnout (#)","Total Voter Turnout (%)","Average votes per minute (08:00-12:00)","Average votes per minute (12:00-17:00)","Average votes per minute (17:00-20:00)"
"2008 Presidential","Precinct","1","39-1","Mikheil Saakashvili","74.48","18.45","1.74","5.92","3.71","0.58","0.12","862","58.24","1.19","1.45","1.05"
"2008 Presidential","Precinct","10","39-10","Mikheil Saakashvili","61.62","24.75","3.03","5.56","5.05","0","0","198","75","0.25","0.34","0.2"
```

**I would like to gather csv of different years of a given precinct, let say `Hzwpukgh`, to one csv that would look like this** :

```
                       2010 Presidential   2017 Presidential ...  
Tprolps Zhhrhzocpsp                67.68                 NaN
Levan Gachechiladze                20.96                 NaN
...
Npvynp Thynclshzocpsp                NaN               64.15
Davit Bakradze                       NaN               13.86
...
```

But, first step, I am looking to merge the csvs into one. So **how to merge files with the same names before the underscore ?**

It would look like :

```
"Election"," Map Level"," Precinct ID"," Precinct Name","Overall Results","#1 - Mikheil Saakashvili","#2 - Levan Gachechiladze","#3 - Shalva Natelashvili","#4 - Arkadi (Badri) Patarkatsishvili","#5 - Davit Gamkrelidze","#6 - Giorgi (Gia) Maisashvili","#7 - Irina Sarishvili-Chanturia","Total Voter Turnout (#)","Total Voter Turnout (%)","Average votes per minute (08:00-12:00)","Average votes per minute (12:00-17:00)","Average votes per minute (17:00-20:00)"
"2008 Presidential","Precinct","1","39-1","Mikheil Saakashvili","74.48","18.45","1.74","5.92","3.71","0.58","0.12","862","58.24","1.19","1.45","1.05"
"2008 Presidential","Precinct","10","39-10","Mikheil Saakashvili","61.62","24.75","3.03","5.56","5.05","0","0","198","75","0.25","0.34","0.2"
...
"2008 Parliamentary-Majoritarian","Precinct","1","39-1","Mikheil Saakashvili","74.48","18.45","1.74","5.92","3.71","0.58","0.12","862","58.24","1.19","1.45","1.05"
"2008 Parliamentary-Majoritarian","Precinct","10","39-10","Mikheil Saakashvili","61.62","24.75","3.03","5.56","5.05","0","0","198","75","0.25","0.34","0.2"
```

Then I would be able to create the dataframe shown above. If you have any other methods I would be very glad to hear them :)

## My attempt

I tried the following :

```
import glob
import random
import os
import pandas

def find_filesets(path="."):
    csv_files = {}
    for name in glob.glob("{}/*_*.csv".format(path)):
        # there's almost certainly a better way to do this
        key = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(name))[0].split('_')[0]
        csv_files.setdefault(key, []).append(name)

    for key,filelist in csv_files.items(): 
        print(key, filelist)
        # do something with filelist
        create_merged_csv(key, filelist)

def create_merged_csv(key, filelist):
    with open('{}-aggregate.csv'.format(key), 'w+b') as outfile:
        for filename in filelist:
            df = pandas.read_csv(filename)
            print(df)
            df.to_csv(outfile, index=False)

find_filesets('./Results')
```

But it returned :

```
01 ['./Results\\01_2016Parliamentary-Majoritarian.csv', './Results\\01_2016Parliamentary-MajoritarianRunoff.csv', './Results\\01_2016Parliamentary-PartyList.csv']
   "Election"," Map Level"," Precinct ID"," Precinct Name","Overall Results","#1 - Initiative Group","#2 - United National Movement","#3 - Free Democrats","#4 - Alliance of Patriots","#5 - Democratic Movement","#6 - Republican party","#7 - Georgia for Peace","#8 - State for the People","#9 - Georgian Idea","#10 - National Forum","#11 - For United Georgia","#12 - Georgia","#13 - Ours - People's Party","#14 - Progressive Democratic Movement","#14 - Georgian Group","#14 - Labour","#14 - Communist Party - Stalin","#14 - Socialist Workers Party","#14 - United Communist Party","#14 - Industrialists - Our Homeland","#14 - Merab Kostava Society","#14 - Leftist Alliance","#14 - In the Name of the Lord","#14 - Georgian Dream","Invalid Ballots (%)","More Ballots Than Votes (#)","More Votes Than Ballots (#)","Total Voter Turnout (#)","Total Voter Turnout (%)","Average votes per minute (08:00-12:00)","Average votes per minute (12:00-17:00)","Average votes per minute (17:00-20:00)"
0   "2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian","Precinct"...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
1   "2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian","Precinct"...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
2   "2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian","Precinct"...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
3   "2016 Parliamentary - Majoritarian","Precinct"...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
...                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:22: ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators (separators > 1 char and different from '\s+' are interpreted as regex); you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-3b33d1e84680> in <module>
      4 import pandas
      5 
----> 6 find_filesets('./Results')

<ipython-input-13-533474b39654> in find_filesets(path)
      9         print(key, filelist)
     10         # do something with filelist
---> 11         create_merged_csv(key, filelist)


<ipython-input-13-533474b39654> in create_merged_csv(key, filelist)
     22             df = pandas.read_csv(filename, sep='delimiter')
     23             print(df)
---> 24             df.to_csv(outfile, index=False, header=None)


C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, tupleize_cols, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal)
   3018                                  doublequote=doublequote,
   3019                                  escapechar=escapechar, decimal=decimal)
-> 3020         formatter.save()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py in save(self)
    170                 self.writer = UnicodeWriter(f, **writer_kwargs)
    171 
--> 172             self._save()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py in _save(self)
    286                 break
    287 
--> 288             self._save_chunk(start_i, end_i)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py in _save_chunk(self, start_i, end_i)
    313 
    314         libwriters.write_csv_rows(self.data, ix, self.nlevels,
--> 315                                   self.cols, self.writer)

pandas/_libs/writers.pyx in pandas._libs.writers.write_csv_rows()

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @balderman, sorry if it was unclear. I updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) takes a file path as an argument, you are giving it an opened file instead.

It can be fixed simply avoiding opening the file:

```
def create_merged_csv(key, filelist):
    outfile = '{}-aggregate.csv'.format(key)
    for filename in filelist:
        df = pandas.read_csv(filename)
        print(df)
        df.to_csv(outfile, index=False)
```

However, this is probably not what you want.
You want to merge/append the data frames first and then write the final file.

Here is an example, assuming that [appending the dataframe](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) is what you want.

```
def create_merged_csv(key, filelist):
    df = [] #init as empty list
    outfile = '{}-aggregate.csv'.format(key)
    for filename in filelist:
        if len(df):
            df1 = pandas.read_csv(filename)
            df = df.append(df1, ignore_index=True)
            print(df1)
        else:
            df = pandas.read_csv(filename)
            print(df)

    df.to_csv(outfile, index=False)
```